# Getting full stack trace for re-thrown exception in PL/SQL (from the point exception originated)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having several nested blocks in `PL/SQL` and in event of error I want to handle error only at the top most level by re-throwing it on the way at each nested level. The problem whenever I am re-throwing (`RAISE`) exception in inner block, `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` resets  the stack to the point, where exception was last raised(which is one of the nested blocks on the way to top level). I could not find the way to get full stack trace right from the point where exception was firstly originated. Any ideas how to get full stack trace, except than logging before re-throwing in intermediate blocks?

Comment: Catching and re-throwing exceptions resets the error stack up to that point where it is raised again. Why are you masking the exception in the first place, if the exception is not handled in the inner blocks it will be automatically propagated to the next level/outer block up to the top level with the correct error and line at which it originated.

Comment: Logging exception in intermediate blocks.

Comment: Again why, what is the point if you are not handling the error in the intermediate blocks to catch it and re-raise it. Exception is automatically propagated through the intermediate blocks up to the top level where it can be handled.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly re-raise it through the intermediate blocks as it is automatically/implicitly "re-raised" through it up to the top level block.

Comment: I am aware of propagation, again there is a requirement to trap exceptions and log the in every intermediate block.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do, and I agree with ivanzg that this is not needed - at the top level handler you can backtrace the entire called stack down to the program and line of the error.

The RAISE statement is the killer for what you are doing. As soon as you do that you've lost the real error location.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to get the full call stack, use a combination of DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK() and DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE(). FORMAT_CALL_STACK will show the top level calls down to the error handler, and FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE will show (accurately) from the error handler down to the error procedure and line of code.

The only downside with FORMAT_CALL_STACK is that the line numbers are not necessarily what you expect - they point you to the error handler.